# Unificar duas ou mais variaves com jupyter notebook

Tags: python

Boa tarde!

Tenho uma base de dados com as variáveis: nº carteirinha, data de internação e data da alta. Quero unificar as três variáveis em uma única com o nome Chave_Internação.

Se for em SAS ficara assim: 
Chave_Internacao = compress(carteirinha || data_internação || data alta);

Porem não estou conseguindo fazer o mesmo no jupyter notebook com python, como posso fazer isso em python?

Comment: Qual o tipo de dados das variáveis? São strings?Ou são colunas de dados em um Pandas dataframe? Ou estão em um banco de dados relacional ("base de dados") - se sim, é necessário ver o código de como você acessa esses dados para ser possível responder a pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se vc deseja apenas concatenar os dados, basta usar o operador `+`.

```py
carteirinha = '12345'
data_internacao = '20190425'
data_alta = '20190426'

var = carteirinha+data_internacao+data_alta
var
```

Lembrando que todos os campos devem estar como `string`, caso não estejam, é possível convertê-los usando `str()`.

Sobre a função compress do SAS, nunca usei, mas imagino que tem um funcionamento parecido com o método [translate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm) do Python

Comment: As varias estão no tipo object, mesmo assim não consigo concatenar.

Comment: o que acontece quando vc tenta, dá erro?